# How do i have a logged in Google account on Android to use C2DM

Tags: android, gmail, android-c2dm

Google says you need a logged in Google account on android to use C2DM.

**Google User Account:** http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#arch

But at the Same time you dont actually need to register that account, you only have to register RegistrationID with C2DM server. So i am confused why they need Gmail account.

i have read somewhere that there is one Gmail account associated with each Android device. So despite that default account **do i need to create separate account for each device ?**.
**is not this default account always logged in on the Android ?**

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance every one

Answer (score 1):

You need one account for C2DM registration as a developer. This is most likely an account of type androidapis@imakeawesomeapps.com. This is to track your API usage, quota etc.

The user (owner of the phone) has to be logged in from his/her Google account on the phone. Thats is all. You don't need to create any account for the user on the phone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. when a user buy a new Android phone do he already has a Gmail account or not. and do he need to create Gmail account and log in to that account to use my app.

Comment: actually i am developing this app for a big company who has so many employees and all of them will be using this app. So my Client dont want to left anything to the employees(to make a Gmail account for themselves and log in to that account) so i was finding a solution for this.. can i solve this problem or i have to left it to employees to make account for them ?

Comment: Google account can be a gmail account or a hosted i.e. Google Apps account. Google Apps account can be created programmatically by the Domain Administrator and set up for each employee. Please check if that "big company" is using Google Apps. http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/provisioning_API_v2_developers_guide.html